# Blender 2.8 rig not fully working on 2.79

Tags: rigging

Hey this may be a silly question but when I made a rig in blender 2.79 (I didn't use rigify) I saved it and opened it on blender 2.8 and by a habit I saved it and now I tried to open it using blender 2.79 and it didn't work when I try to open blender 2.79 it crashes but it still works on 2.8 and I tried the append trick but only parent bones worked 
But the child bones worked when I selected it from the outliner tab 
How can I fix this?

Comment: 2.8 is not backwards compatible with 2.79. You can import from 2.79 to 2.8 but not the other way around.

Comment: Depending on your model (which we unfortunately know nothing about) you can try to export it from 2.80 into a format that contains animations and then import it into Blender 2.79.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender files created with newer versions of Blender should not be opened in older versions of Blender, especially with Blender 2.8 as a lot has changed. What I recommend is having more than one version of Blender installed and/or exporting models and using them in your scenes with newer or older versions of Blender (use DAE format, etc.).

Comment: So it is not possible to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense too because newer versions of Blender have features not present in older versions, and possibly vice versa depending on the case.